# Can anyone tell me what this orange stuff is on my indoor rocket?

Tags: identification, indoors, fungus

[image]

Orange type mould? Around my indoor rocket plant?
What is it?

Comment: what's the plant been growing in in terms of pots?  Is that a peat pot or the actual rootball in the picture?

Comment: They look an awful lot like milkweed bug eggs, but what those would be doing on a peat pot, I don't know...

Comment: @michelle - that was my first thought... weird if they are

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture of [Shocking orange fungus](http://m8.i.pbase.com/u43/trescott/large/33538938.OrangeFungus.jpg).

Well this seems lame even to me. The information is what I am talking about.  Trying to find a scientific name. The way one article was written made it sound like Orange County Mold Attorney was the common name.  Not once but a couple of times.

This picture in the question looks like a peat pot that got put into another pot and has been there some time.  Perfect conditions for this slime mold (not fungus); moisture, substrate, nutrients and darkness. Looks so uniform it could be eggs but eggs hatch and things crawl or fly away.  This has taken some time to form.  Be nice to know the history of this 'pot' as the seedlings now taking root are only a couple of weeks old.  And although this looks like eggs there is just too many of them to account for.

So Orange Fungus or Intensely Orange Fungus or Shockingly Orange Fungus.  But not fungus, a Slime Mold.  How scientific!!? This picture is of [Orange Fungus that looks like eggs](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/9a/9f/66/9a9f667ecb15c80e2a0998194a813b74.jpg).

This link is to information about the orange mold. It's called [Orange Mold and the law](http://orangemolds.com/mold-attorney-orange-county-california/).

Here's another picture of [Orange Slime Mold](https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2570/4169729991_625d694da2_z.jpg).

This source called [All you need to know about Orange Mold](http://orangemolds.com/) has an embedded link to help ID as well.

Guess this article clears up the 'fungus' bit; it is actually a 'slime mold' not a fungus at all.  And reading this article about Orange County Mold Attorney!!  This is not at all good to have in a home!  Zip that right out the door in a black plastic bag.  We'll need to do more work on this ID.  I don't like the "Orange mold and the law" article? Telling you to evacuate the home and have the home thoroughly sterilized?  Whew. Don't do anything as yet except I would take a bread knife and saw the top of that 'pot' with the seedlings right off.  Transplant into another pot with fresh potting soil.  Was this potting soil in the first place?  Be better than trying to transplant each seedling separately.  Use a pot half that size.  I would use two pots and cutting the rocket into two halves using that same knife.  Sterilize knife, put debris into a black plastic bag.  Need to do more investigation before I tell you to pack a bag and evacuate! ha ha ha.  This just can't be right...

Comment: I made substantial edits to this answer, does it take a while to post?

Comment: I'll post a few more links while waiting for my edited answer to show up; http://orangemolds.com/  This one has an embedded link to help ID as well.

Comment: Hi stormy! Edits will show up right away as long as you click on the "Save Edits" that comes up on the bottom of the question. Is it possible you forgot to do that? I tried to help by doing some edits but need you to go over things, because I don't know what, if anything, I did right!

Comment: The links you posted went to pictures, not articles. The link [3], led to a [Pinterest page](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/110690103312152013/). It's just pictures, and needs a login to go further so I took it out. I put the [orangemolds.com](http://orangemolds.com/)  link from your comment in there instead. Now there are both pictures and articles but I don't know what goes where in terms of your text. You should be able to move them around so everything makes sense, but please leave me a note if you have more trouble. I'll check in later!

Comment: Thanks Sue!  I wanted the articles, how the heck I got just the pictures?  Thank you!!  My edited answer found its way back I am so glad.  This answer by no means is final.  I was taken aback by the law stuff.

Comment: The picture posting thing can be confusing. Sometimes we're in an article and click to look at a picture. Then if we copy the link that's on that page, all we get is the picture. We need to go back to the whole article to get the right link address. One easy way to tell is if the link ends in .jpg, that's just going to be the picture. Ending in .com, or sometimes .org, means you're in the source article. Does that help? I hope so!

Comment: @Sue, that is a great 'trick' to know!  Thanks, you bet this helps.  I wish I could find a way to minimize, simplify...this takes some time, these 'essays'.  And I am constantly distracted.  I am working on being less...verbose?